# I am using nest.js and trying to test e2e then when I running test by jest bcrypt is falling it shows that (not a mach-o file)

Tags: docker, jestjs, nest, bcrypt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P0kU.png). and I use macOs m2, running this application by docker as well

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlxEK.png) that all working when testing on postman

I did that uninstall node_modules, package-lock.json and install them again also install less version of bcrypt but that did not help